# How to make variable/strings in a list/tuple infinite and with increasing interval in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is:

```
numberoflines = int(input())
x = 'hi'
y = 'hello'    
orderofwords = [x,y,x,x,y,y,x,x,x,y,y,y]
for n in range(rows):
    print(orderofwords[n])
```

My problem is that I have no idea on how I'm going to make the sequence of order of words infinite so that whatever number I would input, there's always an output. (I want to make an input that ranges from atleast 1-5000)

Ex: input
9
Ex: output 
Hi
Hello
Hi
Hi
Hello
Hello
Hi
Hi
Hi

(All outputs on seperate lines)

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking about. Anyway, you can't make a list or tuple *infinite*, of course, because you don't have infinite memory. You could use a generator, though...

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention that I'm looking for a generator :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41682089/7224320) said, a generator is the best option. So for Python 2 or 3 you could use:

```
def gen(strings, n):
    i, j = (1, 0)
    while True:
        for s in strings:
            for _ in range(i):
              if j < n:
                yield s
                j += 1
              else:
                raise StopIteration
        i += 1

rows = int(input())
strings = ('hi', 'hello') 

for m in gen(strings, rows):
  print(m)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a generator function:

```
def gen(x, y):
    i = 1
    while True:
        yield from [x]*i
        yield from [y]*i
        i += 1
```

Comment: Maybe you should mention that there are no infinite lists and that this code won't work in  Python2 (which the question is tagged).

Comment: @schwobaseggl to be fair, it's *also* taged with Python 3.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga True. This question being asked by an apparent beginner, however, I think one should elaborate a little on how to use the generator and give a hint that the code might not even work in their environment.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really really really bad idea, but as you asked for it, here it is

```
n = 1
list_of_interest = []
while True:
  for i in range (n):
    list_of_interest.append ("x")
  for j in range (n)
    list_of_interest.append ("y")
  n += 1
```

Comment: How am I going to apply that on my code,man? numberoflines = int(input())
x = 'hi'
y = 'hello'    
orderofwords = [x,y,x,x,y,y,x,x,x,y,y,y]
for n in range(rows):
    print(orderofwords[n])